# Fire html button using .cs page

Tags: c#, asp.net

i need to fire html buttom after the end of my asp.net c# code

```
 <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" 
        Text="Button" onclick="Button3_Click" />

<input id="Button2" type="button" value="button" data-type="error" class="growl-type2" runat="server" />
```

and cs code is

```
 protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ----



      i need to fire button2( automatically) in this position
    }
```

Comment: does button2 not have a button_click2 method you could call?

Comment: Refer the accepted answer here http://forums.asp.net/t/1679231.aspx?How+to+programmatically+fire+the+input+button+onclick+event

Answer (score 1):

Button clicks are just handled events. To fire a button click you simply need to raise the correct event.

You'll need something like: `Button2_Click(sender, e)`

Alternatively, you can inject some Javascript into the page, which reacts directly to the click of button3 or is caused by the click of button3 and causes the click of button2 through something like: `document.getElementById('Button2').click()`